# Qt showing a dialog as frameless when called from main window

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I am learning qt and was trying an example from book, where we have to call pre-made dialogs from main window application.

I already made a dialog which will be used to enter a string(lets call it findDialog), the entered string is passed to a custom slot in QTableWidget to search for the entered string.

I can call the dialog as soon as an action called "find" is triggered, but the problem is that the dialog is shown as frameless.

I am calling the dialog like this, please point out any mistakes.

```
void MainWindow::find()
{
    // Check whether findDialog is already created
    if(!finddialog)
    {
        // create find dialog as a child to main window
        finddialog = new findDialog(this);
        // Connecting signals and slots 
     connect(finddialog,SIGNAL(forwardSearch(QString,Qt::CaseSensitivity)),
        sheetObject,SLOT(forwardSearch(QString,Qt::CaseSensitivity)));
      connect(finddialog,SIGNAL(backwardSearch(QString,Qt::CaseSensitivity)),
        sheetObject,SLOT(backwardSearch(QString,Qt::CaseSensitivity)));
    }
    // Show dialog
    finddialog->show();

    finddialog->move(200,200);
    // Raise if minimised
    finddialog->raise();
    // Activate it
    finddialog->activateWindow();
}
```

I cannot use exec because, i haven't connected accept() slot in findDialog to anything.

I am also attaching a picture showing the dialog when it has been called. Please tell me the mistake i have done and how to show the dialog with frame.
[image: findDialog without frame]

Answer (score 1):

Got it,

I have to set window flags using setWindowFlags before showing the dialog.

```
finddialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);
```

to show it as a dialog

```
                  or

finddialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
```

to show it as a window

Comment: Please don't `setWindowFlags` every time you instantiate a `FindDialog`. If `FindDialog` had inherited `QDialog` it would have the `Qt::Window` flags by default, see docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#QDialog) and code [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/dialogs/qdialog.h#n60).

Comment: If you are using examples from the book "C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4", please follow them as they are. `FindDialog` there inherits `QDialog` (see chapter 2 creating dialogs), you will see `class FindDialog : public QDialog`.

Comment: Could you explain what will happen if i set window flags? is it just a bad practise or something happens?...
I should have inherited it from QDialog but i used QWidget, just to check how it works..

Comment: Also it will be better if you post decalaration and definition of `FindDialog` in your question.

Comment: @Kalyan , It is bad practice, if you always have to do calls indicating obvious default behavior. You will never want to have the `FindDialog` being shown without frames. That's why it should be the default behavior in the `FindDialog` class, you don't have to be calling `setWindowFlags` every time you use the class . . .

Comment: @Kalyan , Also, if you don't have `FindDialog` inheriting `QDialog`, I think that you'll run into other problems. As I said, follow the example as it is being written in the book.

Answer (score 0):

You must create `finddialog` with appropriate `Qt::WindowFlags`. See documentation: [Qt::WindowFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum). For example:

```
finddialog = new findDialog(this, Qt::Window);
```

> Indicates that the widget is a window, usually with a window system
>   frame and a title bar, irrespective of whether the widget has a parent
>   or not. Note that it is not possible to unset this flag if the widget
>   does not have a parent.

Also [useful example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html).

Comment: I edited the code but it is showing as 
`error: no matching function for call to 'findDialog::findDialog(MainWindow*, Qt::WindowType)'
         finddialog = new findDialog(this,Qt::Dialog);`

Comment: Even after doing this ---> `public:
     explicit findDialog(QWidget *parent = 0,Qt::WindowType = Qt::Window);
    ~findDialog();`
its still not showing frame.

Comment: If `FindDialog` had inherited `QDialog`, it would have the `Qt::Window` flags automatically, see docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#QDialog) and code [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/dialogs/qdialog.h#n60). Please don't pass something like this every time you want to instantiate a `FindDialog`. Instead make your desired behavior the **default** one, and just instantiate your `FindDialog`.you will have to pass flags **only** when you want flags other than `Qt::Window`.